# how to establish UINavigationController from the 2nd level down (not from the Delegate/RootController level)

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

What would the code be to make use of a UINavigationController in the following circumstance?

- The base application is based on the XCode 4 template "Utility Application", has a MainView & FlipSideView controller  (i.e. MainView does not use a UINavigationController, but modally opens the FlipSideview)
- In the flipside view I have a UITableView that is setup to perform configuration settings
- Want to be able to click on one row of this FlipSideview UITableView and then, using a UINavigationController concept, then transistion across horizontally to a programmatically generated UITableView so the user can select/change the value, then once finished they could click on the BACK BUTTON at the top left (which the UINavigationController would supply)
- Re XIB files then overall, the MainView and FlipSideView would have a XIB file (from the template), but the programmatically generated "select value" view wouldn't have one

So I'm not actually sure where/how to create/hold/use the UINavigationController in this case?  What would the code look like here, where would the UINavigationController variable be held, would the FlipSideView XIB need to be modified?

PS.  In fact would the FlipSideview itself have to change to incorporate a navigation bar at the top?  (then I'd have to mode the existing template's DONE button from it's nav bar, to the new UINavigationController nav bar I guess)

PSS.  Trying this but get an error:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.uiNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    self.navigationController = self.uiNavController; 
    // ==> error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found
}
```

Comment: if i m clear about your question then you want to add a navigation controller not from the app delegate but from any other view controller, m i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this, your FlipSideViewController itself should implement UINavigationControllerDelegate.

How are showing that FlipSideView?

```
FlipSideViewController *flipSideView = [[FlipSideViewController alloc] init..];
[self presentModalViewController:flipSideView animated:YES];
[flipSodeView release];
```

Like this????

Then u have u to change it to

```
FlipSideViewController *flipSideView = [[FlipSideViewController alloc] init..];
UINavigationController *uiNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:flipSideView];
[self presentModalViewController:uiNavController animated:YES];
[flipSideView release]; 
[uiNavController release];
```

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationControllers are designed to be the ROOT view controller of your heirarchy.

So in your example, you should have the FlipSideViewController hold a UINavigationController with the NavigationBar hidden. Then you can PUSH your TableViewController onto the stack as the 'root' view.

When a user taps a cell in your tableview, you can instantiate a new view & PUSH it onto the self.navigationController's stack. Ensure you add code to the new view's viewWillAppear method to show the navigationBar & code to the viewDidDisappear to hide the navigationBar again.